# How can you completely cover the surface of a raster with circles where the radius of the circle is the raster value at its centroid?

Tags: algorithm, topology, mathematics

This is more of an algorithmic/math problem, but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. There's the common problem of covering a surface with circles of equal sizes, but what about UNEQUAL sizes? Where circle size depends on where it's placed? For example, let's say I want to cover California with circles, circle radius = elevation of where it's placed.
[image]

Comment: If you allow overlap you could certainly convert raster cells to points and then generate buffers based upon the original cell value. I think you need to edit your question show some images of what you have and what you want to achieve as I guess people can interpret you question in one of several ways.

Comment: added an example